# Finding a standard generator matrix given a binary code

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, coding-theory, binary

My question is how do I find the standard generator matrix of a binary [7,6,2] code? 
From what I understand a generator matrix for $C$ is any  $ k \times n$ matrix $ G$ with entries in  $ \mathbb{F}_q$ such that the rows of $ G$ form a basis for $ C$. I understand that but where does the 2 (d) come into play? Can someone please explain this to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "standard" generator matrix of a $[n,k]$ code usually means that we seek a $k\times n$ matrix $G$ of the form $$G = \left[I_{k\times k}\  P_{k\times (n-k)}\right]$$ where $I_{k\times k}$ denotes a $k\times k$ identity matrix. For a $[7,6,2]$ code, $P_{6\times 1}$ is just a column of $6$ bits, and I leave it to you to figure what the six bits **must** be in order for the code to have minimum distance $2$. Do it; write out an arbitrary 6-bit column on the right of a $6\times 6$ identity matrix. Then, step back and *admire* the $6\times 7$ matrix that you
have written down, and ponder the fact that each row of $G$ is a codeword.

Comment: \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: Is that really my answer?

Comment: **Yes!!!** As long as you understand _why_ the rightmost column has to be all $1$s.

Comment: Because the minimum weight has to be 2!!! Thanks so much!