# How is a generator matrix built?

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory, binary

If I'm given a set of codewords (i.e. the codewords are **known**) and I know that the code is linear, how can I find the matrix $G$ of that code?

I believe that $G$ is defined as $$G = \left[ P_{k\times (n-k)} \ I_{k\times k}\right]$$

where $I$ is the identity matrix. But I don't know what $P$ is. I don't know how te calculate it either. [In this site I've read that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935758/finding-a-standard-generator-matrix-given-a-binary-code) $P$ is built as a column of all $1$s, but I don't understand why.

So that's the question: how can one find a generator matrix $G$ given the codewords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P_{k\times(n-k)}$ is the *parity check matrix* for the code.

> In this site I've read that $P$ is built as a column of all $1$s, but I don't understand why.

It is not *always* a column of $1$'s, it just is for *that particular code* because the parity check matrix makes sure that the sum of all the digits in the codeword are $0$.

So, if you know your parity check matrix, this is an easy way to construct a generator matrix. (It should also be noted that this formula is written for codes for finite fields of characteristic $2$. You need a negative sign in front of $P$ to make it work for all finite fields.)

> So that's the question: how can one find a generator matrix $G$ given the codewords?

If you have your codewords in hand, then there is no reason to go through the formula above. You can just search your codewords for a set of $k$ linearly independent codewords, where $k$ is the dimension of your code. You can use these as the rows (or columns, depending on your choice of representation) of a generator matrix.

Comment: And how could one calculate the parity check matrix then? The problem is that if the codebook is very long, then finding linearly independent codewords would take a while. I thought that maybe that formula would be  a faster approach to the problem.

Comment: @Tendero To find the parity check matrix, you'd be determining the dual code and then a basis for *that* code. Honestly it is very rare that you should be presented with a code purely as a list of codewords. Are you sure you're not given a generating subset, or some other closed form of the elements?

Comment: To check if they are linearly independent, can I do the same thing I would do with vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$? This would be Gauss elimination

Comment: @Tendero yes, that's right.

Comment: @Tendero I was running into the same problem. Does that mean I just stack all the valid codeword as row of a matrix amd then do Gaussian elimination to obtain the generator matrix ?

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh That would be one way to do it, albeit a computationally expensive one.  You sure you don't have other tools at hand?

Comment: @rschwieb actually my codebook only have 10 codeword (using rref on gf(2) show that it has rank 6) to check, do you have any program that could do this task ?

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh that can’t be a *complete* code book: it doesn’t have a power of $2$ elements.  But anyhow, I imagine any CAS worth a nickel can put a matrix in echelon form.  Do you even need a program? With 10 words it would not be hard.